# Define array as global variable in objective c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsmutablearray, global-variables

i need to define an array as global variable that i can use it all over my code the array must have a data for 10 random number that must be fixed all over the code what i did it the following but with no luck
in the .h file after the @interface i put this line

```
NSMutableArray *globalarray;
```

and in the .m file i put this after the @implemention file

```
- (void)glo {
if (!globalarray) {
 globalarray= [NSMutableArray  globalarray];
    for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++) {
        [globalarray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt: arc4random()%200]];
    }}}
```

and on the same .m file i called the array in NSLOG as follows

```
-(IBAction)click_one:(id)sender{


    NSLog(@"%@",globalarray);}



-(IBAction)click_two:(id)sender{


    NSLog(@"%@",globalarray);}
```

the NSLOG returns null in the console any help is highly apprectaied thanks

Comment: Put `[self glo];` to `init` or `viewDidLoad` method

Comment: I might be wrong, but I'm pretty sure you should be declaring the object as `extern` in the header file and putting the real declaration in a source file.

Comment: thanks but i recived the below

Comment: 2012-08-26 01:26:12.891 sort_alg[1192:207] +[NSMutableArray globalarray]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0xe1cc4c
2012-08-26 01:26:12.895 sort_alg[1192:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+[NSMutableArray globalarray]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0xe1cc4c'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line:

```
globalarray= [NSMutableArray  globalarray];
```

assumes that there's some method on NSMutableArray called "globalarray". There isn't. You want:

```
globalarray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

// in viewDidLoad
self.del = (AppDelegate*) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

// array now available as
NSLog(@"%@", del.dataArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is you assigned autorelease allocation.

```
 GlobalArray=[NSMutableArray array]; is same declarating it as.  

   GlobalArray=[[[NSMutableArray alloc]init]autorelease];
```

// so here reference count increases by 1 when allocating and marking it autorelease makes it reference count to 0. As its reference count becomes 0 it is selected for garbage collection, so you need to retain it, like this

```
 GlobalArray=[[NSMutableArray array]retain];// when retaining its reference count increases by 1
```

Release it when required.